# OpenWeatherMap incorrect current weather temperature

Tags: openweathermap, weather-api

Ive used a about a year both openweathermap, and weatherapi free plans.
Most of the time they both work perfectly. But recently start notice that result between both providers didnt match at all sometimes. Ive found openweathermap sometimes returns just incorrect data.

I am using metric units, and same location.

Here and Example:
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=43.01340753545006&lon=76.92090781210446&units=metric&appid=xxx

returns
"coord": {
"lon": 76.9209,
"lat": 43.0134
},
...
"temp": -23.72
...

But actual temp is -7 celcius. Using weatherapi i get correct result on same location
http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?q=43.01340753545006,76.92090781210446&key=xxx

returns
...
"lat": 43.01,
"lon": 76.92,
"temp_c": -7.0
...

Does anybody met these incorrect results? or what am i doing wrong?
I ve tried ask this quiestion at https://openweathermap.org/ but their "ask a question" form does not work.

Comment: stiil, diffetence between result is 16 degrees, thats huge